# Django: NoReverseMatch with url tag and case-insensitive urls

Tags: regex, django, django-templates

**TLDR; {% url %} tags work. r'(?i)^...$' url paths work. They don't work together?**

I want to use reverse url resolution (via the url template tag), but for whatever reason that doesn't appear to be compatible with case-insensitive url regexes (i.e. regexes prefixed with "(?i)"). To clarify this works:

**urls.py:**

```
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    ...
)
...
```

**base_path.html**

```
<a href="{% url home %}">Users</a>
```

But this causes a NoReverseMatch error:

**urls.py:**

```
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'(?i)^$', home, name='home'),
    ...
)
...
```

Specifically, I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /p/blah/users/
  Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/p/blah/users/
  Django Version:   1.4.3
  Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
  Exception Value:  
    Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
  Exception Location: .../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 424
  Python Executable:    .../bin/python
  Python Version:   2.7.3
```

Any ideas A) why this happens, and/or B) work-arounds for either the url template tag or case-insensitive url regexes? I've reproduced this behavior with a number of our other url paths--all fixed by removing the "(?i)" prefix (although we really want case-insensitivity).

Comment: Which version of django is this?

Comment: @melwil 1.4.3, see the information in the error description :)

Comment: Try putting `(?i)` after `^`.

Comment: @melwil Ah! That works perfectly! I could've sworn those regex directives had to go at the beginning of the expression. If you add an answer I'll mark it and you can get your points :)

Comment: `(?i)` means the same as compiling the regex with re.IGNORECASE. `(?i)` enables case insensitivity for the whole regex in python, and can be put at any point in the regex, even in the middle of it or at the end. I didn't know about this restriction for django though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django url patterns seems to need you to put the regexflags after the `^` anchor.

```
url(r'^(?i)$', home, name='home'),
```